# How to parse String with multiple delimeters into long

Tags: java

I need to parse `String` value into `Long`. Problem is, that value is separated by dots, so they are once groupingSeparator and once decimalSeparator.
So `50.000` should be parsed to `50`, but `5.000.000` need to be parsed to `5000`.
I've tried with `DecimalFormat`, but i cannot set it properly, and ended up with parsing `5.000.000` into `5` since dots were treated as decimalSeparator always.

Comment: The string always ends with `.000`? If so, you could simply strip that part and then parse normally.

Comment: So the last ".000" is always the decimal part? If so. try a `string.replaceAll("\\.000$", ",000")` and try parsing again.

Comment: remove *all* dots, parse and then divide by 1000?

Answer (score 1):

```
String number = "5.000.000";
        String substring = number.substring(0, number.lastIndexOf("."));
        System.out.println(Long.parseLong(substring.replaceAll("\\.","")));
```